# Pyinstaller getting error -"failed to execute script "

Tags: python, pyinstaller

[Please check this Image to see the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZxV5.png)

I have converted to exe file using pyinstaller but it is not running and showing this error in command line. Please tell me how to make it run. In the python program I have one icon picture and one excel file. Also I am running the exe from the same folder where icon and excel are present means I have copied .exe from the dist folder to main folder. Please Help me.

Comment: Can you post your code because right now I think the problem is that you aren't importing the module correctly

Comment: The `pyinstaller` documentation has a very useful section called When things go wrong. I suggest you work through it.

Comment: Hey! pastebin.com/nk0x9bdh This is link to my code you can check. My code is working properly buddy. If u want I can upload excel and .ico file also. And I have also used auto-py-to-exe both of them are also showing error after converting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer by myself (isn't it funny )
To know the solution just see this video - https://youtu.be/2gu5stlEtms

He modified the .spec file and added the imports which are not automatically done by python. This will surely help you

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your code

and if you want to convert from .py to .exe easily try auto-py-to-exe it's a beautiful GUI to convert from py to exe and it may helps you

Comment: Hey! https://pastebin.com/nk0x9bdh This is link to my code you can check. My code is working properly buddy. If u want I can upload excel and .ico file also. And I have also used auto-py-to-exe both of them are also showing error after converting.